# How do you install applications

Tags: wireless, software-installation

I'm trying to switch over to U from windows. All of this is new to me. I just installed U14.04 on my laptop. I want to be wireless. I have downloaded wifi-radar 2.0.s05-1.1.deb How do I install it? Because it recommended i also downloaded Aptitude_0.4.11.11.orig. How do I get it to install?

Comment: Why did you download wifi-radar? Doesn't Wi-Fi work out of the box? By the way, you should never manually download packages from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

## Install directly via Ubuntu Software Center

Instead of downloading a *.deb file and manually installing it, you can install programs directly via the ubuntu repositories:

1) Open the Ubuntu Software Center.

2) Search for the package you want to install.

3) Select the package, click on install and follow the instructions.

## Install .deb files via the Ubuntu Software Center:

1) Open Nautilus File Browser and go to the directory containing the *.deb file

2) Double click the *.deb file. The Ubuntu Software Center should open up.

3) Click on Install and follow the instructions.

## Install .deb files via command line interface:

1) Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)

2) Change the directory to where the file is placed, e.g.

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

3) Enter

```
sudo dpkg -i *name*.deb
```

4) Press enter

5) Enter your password (don't get confused: no letters will be visible) and press enter again